# Gradle bndProjectBuilder test

Tags: java, gradle, jboss-arquillian, bnd, liferay-7

I am trying to write integration tests for liferay 7 portlets with gradle, arquillian and bnd tool.

This is my deployment method in the test class:

```
@Deployment
public static JavaArchive create() throws IllegalArgumentException, FileNotFoundException {
    print("Eseguo il Deployment");

    BndProjectBuilder bndProjectBuilder = ShrinkWrap.create(BndProjectBuilder.class);

    bndProjectBuilder.setBndFile(new File("bnd-test.bnd"));
    bndProjectBuilder.generateManifest(true);
    JavaArchive j = bndProjectBuilder.as(JavaArchive.class);        
    return j;
}
```

And this is the bnd-test.bnd file:

```
Bundle-Name: Beep Col Portlet Test
Bundle-SymbolicName: it.polimi.metid.beep.beepcol.test
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Include-Resource:build/classes/main,META-INF/resources=src/main/resources/META-INF/resources
Require-Capability:\
osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=jsp.taglib)(uri=http://liferay.com/tld/ddm))",\
osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=jsp.taglib)(uri=http://liferay.com/tld/frontend))",\
osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=jsp.taglib)(uri=http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0))",\
osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=jsp.taglib)(uri=http://liferay.com/tld/aui))",\
osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=jsp.taglib)(uri=http://liferay.com/tld/portlet))",\
osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=jsp.taglib)(uri=http://liferay.com/tld/theme))",\
osgi.extender;filter:="(&(osgi.extender=jsp.taglib)(uri=http://liferay.com/tld/ui))",\
osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

-jsp: *.jsp,*.jspf
-plugin.bundle: com.liferay.ant.bnd.resource.bundle.ResourceBundleLoaderAnalyzerPlugin
-plugin.jsp: com.liferay.ant.bnd.jsp.JspAnalyzerPlugin
-plugin.sass: com.liferay.ant.bnd.sass.SassAnalyzerPlugin
-sass: *
-sources: true
-dsannotations: *
```

With functional tests this works fine but the problem comes out when i try to do some Integration tests and try to use external libraries like
com.liferay.portal:com.liferay.portal.test;version='1.0.0' 

When I am going to use some classes of this library like this:

```
@Test
public void prova() throws Exception {
    Group g = GroupTestUtil.addGroup();     
}
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/kernel/test/util/GroupTestUtil
```

I think that's because the BndProjectBuilder does not include the dependencies jar, or I bad configure the bnd file.

Someone has already encountered this problem?

Comment: Could you please post your build.gradle and your imports on the test class? I have some trouble getting tests up and running with gradle. My injections are always null. You can find an example module I try to get running in my liferay forum question: https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/85975754

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any real understanding of Arquillian or its Liferay integration, so this answer is based in part on experiment and speculation.

`GroupTestUtil` should already be available in the Liferay runtime through the bundle `com.liferay.portal.test`. It's easy enough to check that the class exists and is exported.

The OSGi framework builds a bundle's classpath at resolution-time based on the contents of the Import-Package instruction in its manifest; classes whose package isn't referenced in that list are unavailable to the bundle. It's usually not a problem when using a manifest generation.

Your test class has probably been compiled to a different build directory than the module under test. Although Arquillian will run its tests in the same classpath as the deployed bundle (according to my testing), the test class isn't used by bnd to generate the Import-Package instruction, isn't part of the bundle, but isn't able to use packages not referenced in the bundle.

The fix is straightforward. Explicitly import `GroupTestUtil`'s package in your bnd-test.bnd:

```
Import-Package: \
    com.liferay.portal.kernel.test.util,\
    *
```

(The `*` on the second line instructs bnd to continue generating other imports on its own.)

Comment: Finally i found the problem.
Simply the com.liferay.portal.kernel.test.util bundle was not installed in portal.

Comment: I could have sworn I saw com.liferay.portal.kernel.test in the list of installed bundles, but you seem to be right. Good catch.